# Is there a way to place a '>' sign at the beginning of a line using PHP?

Tags: php

If I have a textarea like the one I'm using to type this message. I would like to append or concat a '>' to every line that breaks. The problem I am having is that I don't know where the lines break. What I want to do is emulate an email message when someone replies, they see '>' appended to every line. Is there a function for this?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean prepended to every line by the way

Comment: well, prepend isn't actually a word. How about prefix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's for an email message, you could take a string and use the [wordwrap](http://php.net/wordwrap) function to break at about 75 chars:

```
$reply='> '.wordwrap($original, 75, "\n> ");
```

Because you can supply your own break string, you can include the `>` right there!

If the original is already broken into lines, then simply replace existing line break:

```
$reply='> '.str_replace ("\n", "\n >", $original);
```

Comment: Hey Paul, I'm gonna give this a shot. I think this may work. brb.

Comment: Should maybe use PHP_EOL instead of \n?

Comment: Thanks Svish. Paul?? What do you think?

Comment: If it's for an email, \n is fine (we don't necessarily want the *system's* idea of what a line break is)

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Thanks again for all the help, guys.

Comment: Don’t forget the `>` in the first line.

Answer (score 0):

How about replacing all line-breaks with a line-break and a greather-than? Something like this perhaps:

```
$subject = str_replace (PHP_EOL, PHP_EOL.'>', $subject);
```

Comment: Hi Svish. I just tied a string into that but it doesn't concat anything.

Comment: It doesn't concat anything. It puts a '>' after every linebreak in the $subject string, like you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [str_replace()](http://www.php.net/str_replace) function in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

A little better for email quoting is:

```
$text = $_POST['text'];
$text = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $text);
$text = str_replace("\r", "\n", $text);

$text = str_replace("\n", "\n> ", $text);
$text = wordwrap($text, 75, "\n> ");
$text = str_replace("\n> >", "\n>>", $text);
$text = ($text[0] == '>' ? '>' : '> ') . $text;
$text = htmlspecialchars($text);
```

This adds the always-useful space between the '>' and the text, while not bloating it by adding spaces between multiple quote levels.

Even better is if you can make it not wordwrap lines that are already quoted in the original message.  Better still, implement format=flowed.  But either of these'll take considerably more code.

Answer (score 0):

First off, thanks to Paul Dixon - great and simple idea :)
Anyway I had some two problems with the solution:
empty lines and lists (which have already *\n* linebreaks) wouldn't begind with *>* and long links are not cut after the given number of charaters.

So here is my extension to Pauls idea:

```
$reply = wordwrap($original, 75, "\n", true);
$reply = '> '.str_replace ("\n", "\n> ", $reply);
```

The first line wraps *$original* to 75 chars, breaks with *\n* and forces breaking of long words (*ie: urls*). The second line replaces the line breaks with a break and the *>* and adds an extra > to the beginning of the whole string.

Maybe this could be done easier but it works for me ;)

Answer (score -1):

You mean on the client side? You'll need to do that in javascript.

Comment: It isn't clear whether the OP is actually writing a webmail or similar program and implementing the reply facility (IWC server-side makes most sense), or just writing a facility for the user to type or c&p text in and turn it into quoted form (IWC client-side makes most sense). But the fact that he asked how to do it in PHP implies to me that he wants to do it server side, either because it's an actual reply facility or so that it still works if JS is disabled

Comment: Yes, it's obvious now that he's confirmed an answer; but lots of new programmers don't understand the different between server and client languages; and the fact that he said 'textarea' (which doesn't exist at the server side) indicated to me that it was clientside. I was wrong. No big deal.